# How to resolve paypal (Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)) error in magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: orders, payment-methods, paypal

I have removed the Order review steps in Checkout page. After that PayPal payment has stopped working. Before the changes, PayPal was working fine.

Referred Url:-
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/skip-order-review.html

I have updated the file by given step in above mentioned URL. It's working fine for bitpay payment.

Two kind of payment method having in onepage checkout.
1.Paypal
2.Bitpay

I tried to pay using PayPal it's getting shows alert box "true".

> Paypal response:
>
> success:false
>
> error:    true
>
> error_messages:   PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token
> (#10410: Invalid token)."

Comment: There are several different PayPal payment method integrations available out of the box in Magento 1.9. Some allow you to take payment without leaving your site, others require the customer to be redirected to PayPal and then redirected back to your website. Which integration method are you using?

Comment: Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout).